# gvisGeoChart India province level

Tags: r, google-maps, gvisgeomap

I am looking to use gvisGeoChart for provinces of India.
G <- gvisGeoChart(ageProfile, "State", "Males", options=list( region = "IN", displayMode="regions", resolution="provinces" ))
[image]

But i am looking for the right visual for India just like the visual of US. Your help would be appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fill data array with real values, but to give you an idea of what it will look like:

```
  function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Population'],,
    ['West Bengal', 24],
    ['Gujarat', 25],
    ['Assam', 29],
    ['Punjab', 23],
    ['Delhi', 30],
     ...

  ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'IN',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    width: 640, 
    height: 480
  };
  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, options);
};
```